# How can I install Nvidia control panel?

Tags: windows-10, driver, nvidia

Got an message in Windows 10(1903) about it not finding Nvidia control panel.
Message: "Nvidia control panel not found"

I have downloaded and installed the latest Nvidia drivers for my grafic card but I don't understand why the control panel is not being installed when the driver is installed.
Anyway I found some information that says that I need to install the Nvidia control panel from MS Store but here comes the problem, I have no internet access from that particular computer. I guess I want to download it from MS Store or somewhere else but where?

Is there any other trick to get the control panel for Nvidia to work?

best regards,
Hans

Comment: Better to install nvidia clean driver and it's automatically optimize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed an older driver version and that works with the control panel. The new driver does not.